# Opening a new fragment from within a ViewPager in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a question about opening a new fragment from within a ViewPager.

I setup FragmentA, FragmentB and FragmentC to be fragments of a viewpager and then proceeded to setup Fragment1 and Fragment2 as fragments of another viewpager which resides in FragmentB.

So Fragment1 and Fragment2 are in a viewpager which is essentially nested in another viewpager. I'm playing around with UI styles etc and this is is similar to that found in the Flickr app.

The problem I'm having is that once I get into the fragment1 or fragment2 (the nested fragment) I want to be able to click on something and enter a full screen fragment bypassing the toolbar I set up in FragmentB.

Below is the the code I have for FragmentB with the toolbar, tablayout and viewpager.

```
package com.app.fragmentdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {


    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFragmentB);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((FragmentActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(),"Fragment 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(),"Fragment 2");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I've put together for fragment2 which contains a button I would like to take to take me to another fragment.

```
package com.app.fragmentdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2,container,false);

        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment fragment = new FragmentFull();
                FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.fragmentFullContainer,fragment);
                ft.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Upon clicking the button the app crashes. I get the error:

No view found for id 0x7f080084 (com.app.fragmentdemo:id/fragmentFullContainer) for fragment FragmentFull

If I change the id of the fragment container to the id I assigned to the Fragment2 layout file, it works fine. However, this is still contained in the nested viewpager and doesn't allow me to enter a new layout.

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is this function [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) which is for nested fragments. But I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line

```
ft.add(R.id.fragmentFullContainer,fragment);
```

`fragmentFullContainer` should be a view in your `R.layout.fragment_2`

You are getting the crash because the OS cannot find `fragmentFullContainer` in `R.layout.fragment_2`

**UPDATE**

replace `getSupportFragmentManager` with `getChildFragmentManager`

**If you want full screen , you have to manually hide Activity View elements.**

Most probably, you have toolbar from activity, you can remove it like that.

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: I can change it so that it calls a view in the R.layout.fragment_2 and you're right it does display and I don't get the error. However, the fragment would replace the existing fragment in the viewpager. I'd like it to create a new fragment which isn't part of the viewpager and can be made fullscreen.